# Community change email verification redirecting to home/home.jsp

Tags: community, force.com-sites

We have a Site configured to display a Visualforce page for our community members.
However, when the the community user changes their email, they get an email to verify the change. We modified this template, and it includes a link to verify the change `{!ChgEmailVer.URL}`.
Clicking that link sends the user to a verification page where they click the button that they confirm the change.
The user is then redirected to `/home/home.jsp`, even though the Site home is configured to be a Visualforce page.

How can we fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a workaround, not a solution!

We set the site redirect with a 301 from `/home/home.jsp/` to the internal page we want.

Comment: Couldn't  understand how  set the site redirect with a 301 from /home/home.jsp/ to the internal page we want.

Can you please provide steps. I want to redirect to community URL when community user click email  and redirect to confirmation , when user click continue should redirect community login instead of Salesforce login.

Comment: There's a thing here explaining how it's done: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.siteforce_redirects.htm